# Simplest way to attach a function to [onload, on a set of elements click, and on another set of elements click]?

Tags: jquery

I'm having a hard time finding the syntax or even just an elegant solution for this.

I want to implement a "currently viewing" label for a carousel that is used to preview additional images. I inject the label into each slide from the server but set them with the class hidden.

Here is my function:

```
var api = $('#imageNav').data('tabs');
var currentImageId = '#' + api.getCurrentPane().attr('id');
var $carousel = $('#carousel_slides');

$carousel.find('a > span').addClass('hidden')
                          .parentsUntil($carousel).find('a[href=\"' +
                           currentImageId + '\"] > span').removeClass('hidden');
```

I'd like to be able to run that function on 3 different events:

```
1. DocumentReady()
2. $('#imageNav li > a').click()
3. $('#carousel_slides span > a').click()
```

Is there a way to combine all 3 with .on() or do I have to set it up for all 3 individually?

Thanks.

**EDIT** - I tried this in my   $(function () {}); but no luck.

```
var SetCurrentlyViewingLabel = function() {
    var api = $('#imageNav').data('tabs');
    var currentImageId = '#' + api.getCurrentPane().attr('id');
    var $carousel = $('#carousel_slides');
    $carousel.find('a > span').addClass('hidden')
             .parentsUntil($carousel).find('a[href=\"' + currentImageId + '\"] > span')
             .removeClass('hidden');
};

SetCurrentlyViewingLabel();

$('#imageNav li > a, #carousel_slides span > a').click(SetCurrentlyViewingLabel());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can combine 2 and 3 with a comma.  The first I'm not sure how to implement.

```
$('#imageNav li > a, #carousel_slides span > a').click()
```